# Update field values that is inside a json document IN db2

Tags: sql, json, db2, db2-luw

{
"identifier": "108",
"name": "HEALTH CLINIC",
"languageSupported": [
{
"Language": "English",
"selected": false
},
{
"Language": "Spanish",
"selected": true
}
],
"defaultLanguage": "Spanish"
}

I am able to update the json objects with the below query.

```
UPDATE JSONTABLE SET
JSONCOL=SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE(JSONCOL,
         '{ $set: {"name":"AMC HEALTH CLINIC"}}') WHERE DELETE_FLAG='N';
```

Now I want to change the data in below node "Language supported".
In place of "French" I want to update "Spanish". Below query i'm using to update. but i didn't able to
get the updated data.

```
UPDATE JSONTABLE SET
JSONCOL=SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE(JSONCOL,
      '{ $set: {"Language.1":"French"}}') WHERE DELETE_FLAG='N';
```

and i tried with below query as well.

```
UPDATE JSONTABLE SET
JSONCOL=SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE(JSONCOL,
'{ $set: {"languageSupported.Language.1":"French"}}') WHERE DELETE_FLAG='N';
```

Output should be like this:
languageSupported": [
{
"Language": "English",
"selected": false
},
{
"Language": "Spanish",
"selected": true
}

Can any one help me to understand how to update the data within a node in db2 luw. do we have possibility to update any type of field's value inside the json.

Comment: What is JSON doc after your UPDATE statement? Is the field updated or a new one added to the document? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070292.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but my guess is a query like this:

```
UPDATE JSONTABLE SET
JSONCOL=SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE(JSONCOL,
'{ $set: {"languageSupported.1.Language":"French"}}') WHERE DELETE_FLAG='N';
```

**languageSupported** is at the top for the path, then you need to select the 2nd element in the array ("1"), next the **Language** key.

Comment: Hi Henrik, Thanks for the answer. tried with your solution. but it's not working. Field is not updated.